# mysterious pixel in table -for newsletter-

Tags: html, css, border

HTML

```
<table>
        <tr>
           <th>
                <h1>Esta semana hablamos de....</h1>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
                <h2>Nuestra Cultura</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. 
                </p>
            </td>
        
        </tr> 
    </table>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    table{ position:relative;margin:0px auto;width:650px;background:url(fnd.jpg) center bottom no-repeat; padding: 0 25px 75px; font-family:arial;}
    table th{ width:600px; }
    table th h1{font-size:30px;color:#808080;}
    h1,h2,p{text-align:left;padding:0px 20px;}
    table td h2{font-weight:bold;margin:0;padding:0;}
    table tr{ width:600px;}
    table td{background:white;}
    td, th, tr { margin:0;border:0;}
</style>
```

The problem is that in the td, tr or h2 there is a pixel I can't make disappear, the problem is that is splitting the background which I don't want... what I am doing wrong?

-EDIT-

you can see here

[image]

and test here http://toniweb.us/melia/mail/

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't show anything, because you've put your HTML in the Javascript pane. Moving it to the HTML pane works, but your problem is still not apparent.

Comment: Fixed your jsfiddle but can't see anything here. Sure it's not some bg image or something?

Comment: I faced this problem once before, turned out to be some mess on my screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default style for `<table>` is often

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
```

If you don't want any space between rows then add

```
border-spacing: 0;
```

for `table` line 6.

EDIT: IE7 simply doesn't know border-spacing, if it's a matter you must use `border-collapse:collapse;` and adjust space with padding.

Comment: any idea why is it so different in IE7 ??